# Ajax request won't trigger. [Yii framework]

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have a little problem with a Controller method AJAX call in Yii. The thing is that I'm trying to filter the data of one dropDownList based in the value of a previous selected item.

In the view file, where I figured out is the source of the problem, I have this piece of code:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Estado'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'estado',CHtml::listData(Estado::model()->findAll(),'id','nombre'),array(
            'ajax'=>array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>CController::createAbsoluteUrl('buscar/select'),
            'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'tbl_municipio_id'),
            ),
            'class'=>'form-control'     
        )); 
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'Estado'); ?>
```

On the Controller side, I got this:

```
public function actionSelect(){
    echo "Hello world";
    $data = Municipio::model()->findAll('tbl_estado_id=:tbl_estado_id',
            array(':tbl_estado_id'=>(int) $_POST['Consultorio_estado']));   

    $data = CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
                array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
```

The ajax call to the Select method isn't triggered when the dropDownList is clicked. I tracked the request using Firebug and no error nor fail message is dropped.

Anyone knows what can I do?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With my knowledge in `Yii 1.1.13`, there is no such option for `ajax` for `form->dropDownList`, just `Chtml::dropDownList` does.

Therefore you have option to manually custom event change of `form->dropDownList` or add more jQuery script to handle it by yourself, or simply switch to use `Chtml::dropDownList` like below example

```
 <?php
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('inst_province','',
        array(1=>'A',2=>'B',3=>'C', 4=>'D'),
        array(
            'prompt'=>'Select City',
            'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('city/selectAll'),
                'update'=>'#city_area',
                'data'=>array('city_param'=>'js:this.value'),
            )));
    ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/429/an-easy-solution-for-dependent-dropdownlist-using-ajax/